# How can I iterate this code without using such a complicated for loop?

Tags: python

I have this `for` loop:

```
COMPANY2 = ['"tesla', 'motors', 'inc"']

COMPANY3 = []

for x in range(0, len(COMPANY2)):

    globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x] = list(COMPANY2[x])

    if x == 0:

        globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x][1] = globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x][1].upper()

    else:

        globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x][0] = globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x][0].upper()

        COMPANY3.append(''.join(globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x]))

    del globals()['COMPANY3_%s' % x]
```

And I'm wondering if there is an easier way to call `upper()` on the first letter of each item, than making and deleting all these globals.

Comment: Consider `str.title()`?

Comment: Besides the wrong use of ```globals``` I find it hard to understand what this code supposed to do? what's the expected result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
company_3 = [o.title() for o in company_2]
```

If I understand correctly what you are trying to achieve, not sure